# Convergence in $L^p$ and $L^q$ - multiplication

Tags: probability

We have: $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^p$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in $L^q$. Moreover $p,q>1$ are such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} =1$. Prove that $X_nY_n \rightarrow XY$ in $L^1$. Please, can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Hölder. We have $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$ 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{XY-X_nY_n}_1 &\le \norm{XY - XY_n}_1 + \norm{XY_n - X_nY_n}_1\\
      &\le \norm X_p\norm{Y-Y_n}_q + \norm{X-X_n}_p\norm{Y_n}_q 
\end{align*}
Now $(Y_n)$ is bounded in $L_q$, hence both terms tend to zero. So we are done.